# Can I cast spells in the middle of another spell resolving?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Say I had [Vedalken Orrery](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Vedalken%20Orrery) and I used [Cloudshift](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Cloudshift) on something, could I respond to Cloudshift bringing the creature back into play with [Day of Judgement](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Day%20of%20Judgement) or something similar?

Comment: Note that DoJ is a sorcery, so you can't ordinarily cast it in response to anything.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, Cloudshift is resolved as a single, atomic event.  There is no time in between the parts of its effect in which anyone has a window of opportunity to cast a spell.

From the Comprehensive rules:

> 116.2e Resolving spells and abilities may instruct players to make choices or take actions, or may allow players to activate mana
>   abilities. Even if a player is doing so, no player has priority while
>   a spell or ability is resolving. See rule 608, "Resolving Spells and
>   Abilities."

Comment: spells are not quite atomic, For instance, if you cast `Living Death`, all of the dies triggers will be put on the stack before any of the ETB triggers.

Comment: @SamIam no, that's not right. All the dies trigger will trigger before the ETB trigger. However, triggers are not put on the stack just at the moment they triggered, but only before a player would get priority. Players can put the ETB triggers on the stack before the dies triggers.

Comment: However, it's true that Cloudshift is not a single, atomic event. Exiling and returning the creature to play are two different sequential events. Players can't play anything between these two events because the don't get priority, not because it's a single event.

Comment: I more meant that the resolution was atomic, in the sense that there's no space for anything not written on the card to happen until the card has finished resolving, rather than that everything on the card happens simultaneously.  Probably an unwise choice of term, I guess...

Answer (score 2):

"To respond to X" means "to cast or activate after X is placed on the stack but before X resolves."

One can respond to [Cloudshift](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Cloudshift), but not to "bringing creature back". That's not a spell, activated ability or triggered ability. You do not get priority in the middle of a spell resolving [CR 116.2e].

If you cast [Day of Judgement](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Day%20of%20Judgement) in response to Cloudshift, it you would resolve before Cloudshift does anything at all. Cloudshift cannot save a creature from Day of Judgement, but [Fiend Hunter](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Fiend%20Hunter) and [Sudden Disappearance](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Sudden%20Disappearance) could.

Answer (score 1):

I would say no, Cloudshift removes and puts back a creature as part of the same effect, so you cannot 'inturrupt' the effect in the middle of its action by casting some other spell. You could Day of Judgement before you cast or after you cast cloudshift, but you cannot remove your own creature, Day of Judgment, and then put it back.